# What are the possible causes of a not-booting motherboard with drdebug 00 code?

Tags: boot, motherboard, post

I have pursached a new Asrock Z68 Extreme4 motherboard with an i7 2600K and 2x4GB ADATA DDR3. My problem is that it doesn't boot or beep, and the onboard drdebug led constantly displays "00" - which is according to the board's manual, "not used". The power cables are probably conntecting, because if I disconnect the 4+4 or 20+4 cable, nothing is displayed on the leds.

Has anybody seen this error? What are the possible causes?

Answer (score 0):

I could be a short circuit in the motherboard. Is it fastened to the chassis with the supporter pins? Make sure it isn't touching anything metal.

Another issue could be your power supply. It may be faulty or not be giving enough power/voltage to the motherboard, so it refuses to boot in order to prevent damage. A multimeter would help in testing your PSU.

Comment: Unfortunately multimeter helps quite little with PSU/MB boot issues - unless it's some very clear issue, you'd need an oscilloscope to see if voltages drop for brief moments during the boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try dry running it - put newspaper on table, just the motherboard and pc speaker and PSU connected, and then start it by shorting the power switch pins on motherboard. This should help you to rule out the other components. If the display still stays 00, then it's either bad mobo or PSU. If it doesn't start adding components one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Brand new motherboard?   Check the jumper for the CMOS battery.   It's probably on the 'clear' setting, which removes the battery from the circuit to keep it fresh for the new owner... but it usually also puts the motherboard into a 'wait-state' ... nothing runs, nothing works, just the fans, maybe.

Flip the jumper to the 'normal' or 'bios' setting, and all should be well.